# Windows Networking - Treat two subnets as one network

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, windows-server-2008-r2, subnet

We have an existing (old) network (10.0.0.0/24) and we're trying to add another (new) subnet (20.0.0.0/24) using a Cisco 2901 router. I added the appropriate routes and tested everything out. We're good. I can ping across to the old subnet, can get to the Internet, etc.

On the new subnet we have a Cisco 2504 WLC with a few access points. The WLC hands out DHCP. I can connect to that network and get online.

On the old subnet we have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2. Windows Firewall is turned off both on this server and on all clients. Due to some organizational constraints we have to be able to browse to \Server1 from our new subnet but we cannot.

In other words, a client on the old network can see the server under "Networking" in Windows. a client on the new network cannot, but if you manually browse to \10.x.x.x (The server's IP) I can access everything as expected. So, the question is this...

In this scenario, how can I get a network of Windows 7 Pro machines on multiple subnets to see this all as one network from a Windows perspective? Note there is no domain controller, no ADDS, etc. This Server is the only one on our network and just acts as a file share of sorts.

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned you should not use 20.0.0.0 but something like 10.2.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Seeing" the network is a function of several components, but is largely facilitated by NetBIOS broadcasts. Broadcast traffic is typically blocked by a router. You can do one of two things:

1. Configure the router to forward broadcast traffic between the two networks.
2. Install and configure a WINS server and configure all of your clients to use the WINS server.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc787830(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the input, that lets me know I was at least on the right track. Am I defeating the purpose of subnetting by passing broadcast traffic across this new router? Right now our broadcast domain is huge... eg: the entire building!

Comment: That's a bit of a misconception. The size of the physical and logical subnet allows for the `potential` to have a large broadcast domain but in reality the volume of broadcast traffic is a function of the number of hosts/computers on the network, not it's physical or logical size. If you have 100 hosts/computers then you have 100 hosts/computers worth of broadcast traffic, whether the physical/logical network supports 100 or 10,000 hosts.